# Java Graphics2D drawString wrap text

Tags: java, graphics

How do you go about wrapping strings using Graphics2D drawString.

Saw some examples like this 
[drawstring replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400566/full-justification-with-a-java-graphics-drawstring-replacement)

But this does not work since I have a vertically aligned text and the fontmetrics height from graphics  gives me 0.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you're using where the FontMetrics gives you a zero height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JTextArea?

This [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083322/how-can-i-create-a-jtextarea-with-a-specified-width-and-the-smallest-possible-hei/4083850#4083850) shows how the text area can be sized to fit the text.