# JLabel into GridBagLayout. How to fix the width?

Tags: java, swing, layout, text, jlabel

I have a very simple JLabel with a quite long text. 
The parent layout is a GridBagLayout.
I want the width of the containing Frame not to exceed a certain value, say 160 pixel.
So I set the text as "html", so as the JLabel is able to wrap the text into multiple lines. 
Now I just want to "fix" the JLabel width. But I haven't found a way. 
The maximum size of the Jframe, the JLabel is not checked by layout manager, so i don't know if there's a "plain" solution. 

The very simple example (just fix imports to run) shows  the situation.

```
public class SSCE extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new SSCE().setVisible(true);
    }

    public SSCE() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen");
        add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridy=1;
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("other content");
        add(label2, gbc);

        pack();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying the width in the HTML, like this:

```
String html = 
    "<html><body width='150px'>" +
    "Some content that will span 150 pixels and then line-wrap as necessary" +
    "</body></html>";
new JLabel( html );
```

Note that I've specified pixels (`150px`) in this example, but HTML body width can be specified other ways.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Huh? That's just some arbitrary number, the point is that you can specify width this way. In fact, you're the person who showed me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083322/how-can-i-create-a-jtextarea-with-a-specified-width-and-the-smallest-possible-he/4093402#4093402) :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Ha :D. I saw your edit, I didn't know about pixels being the default. I'm willing to bet that a relative size (`150%`) wouldn't work here as there's no parent HTML component, right?

Comment: *"..right?"*  Your JRE is as good as mine.  What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to use `prefered` and `maximum` sizes for `JLabel` ?

Comment: label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80,Integer.MAX_VALUE)); tried,  of course. It doesn't work. In the javadoc, GridBagLayout is said to consider max value. Perhaps it evaluate max value in other circumstances, for example when it redistribute extra space... i don't know. It's rather complex for me to comprehend all the details of this layout manager.

Comment: I think Maximum and Prefered sizes should be equal to your maximum value , in your case is 160 .

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar question: "make a JLabel wrap it's text by setting a max width"

And this answer seems to be the right one:[JLabel Max Width Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420742/make-a-jlabel-wrap-its-text-by-setting-a-max-width/2420834#2420834)