# how to make JTextPane the size of a piece of paper?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextpane

OK, So i finally figured out how to print a `JTextPane`, and really have a fully functioning document editor.

Anyway, Can I make the `JTextPane` the size of a piece of paper (with page breaks) So you can easily predict the appearance of the document you are typing? Any tips/hints would be helpful!

edit: format of the `JTextPane` is *'text/rtf'*, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the links could help

http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane.html

http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane_Print.html

Answer (score 1):

The `Printable` returned by the [`getPrintable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getPrintable%28java.text.MessageFormat,%20java.text.MessageFormat%29) method of `JTextComponent` "formats the document content appropriately for the page size." If this is insufficient, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you're having.

Comment: I see how it prints it fine, but how can i make the JTextPane appear as documents do in Word, like pieces of paper, and the right size?

Comment: I usually rely on the host platform's preview capabilities, but you could interrogate existing [*Print Services and Attributes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a layout manager

[How can I create a JTextArea with a specified width and the smallest possible height required to display all the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083322/how-can-i-create-a-jtextarea-with-a-specified-width-and-the-smallest-possible-he)

As for setting the width, you'll want to calculate it based on the page format specified.  It could be 8.5x11 or in landscape or a completely different size altogether.

```
pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
pageFormat.getImageableHeight();
```